# What will be the event name for checkbox checked event while using ajax trigger asynchronous call?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-3.5

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
      <Triggers>
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chkStaySignedIn" EventName="Checked" /> 
      </Triggers>
      <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password" AssociatedControlID="txtPassword"/>
     </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**EventName="Checked"**
Can anyone provide me a link to complete list of event names while using ajax.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The checkbox's event name is `CheckedChanged`

It isn't a definitive list by any means, but [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.eventname.aspx) lists the default event names for common controls that post back.

Comment: Are there any other events also that are supported by event name property ?
Is it there any other method also to get event name within VS